# Undefined variable: _get XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, html, get, xampp

I'm just trying to add two integers using PHP and XAMP.

I've placed my client.html file and service.php (which add numbers) in C:\xampp\htdocs

and I get

> "Notice: Undefined variable: _get in C:\xampp\htdocs\service.php on
>   line 7

Notice:

> Undefined variable: _get in C:\xampp\htdocs\service.php on line 8"
>   error.

Before posting this error to Stack Overflow. Let me tell you that I double checked my file names, variable names case-sensitive etc everything. but still having the same error. Any help will be really appreciated.

This is my client.html

```
form action="service.php" method="get">
    input type="text" name="txt1"> <br />
    input type="text" name="txt2"> <br />
    input type="submit" value="add"><br />
```

and here is service.php

```
<?PHP

echo "This is my first program in php";
$a= $_get['txt1'];
$b= $_get['txt2'];
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Comment: `$_GET`. Also use `POST` more secure

Comment: If you want, you can also use `$_POST` instead because it's more secure since the user can't see it in the url. `$_GET` will be transmitted in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` is a `SUPER GLOBAL VARIABLE` and to access it you have to use `$_GET`.

So do like below:-

```
<?PHP

echo "This is my first program in php";
$a= $_GET['txt1'];
$b= $_GET['txt2'];
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Note:-

using `POST` is more secure than `GET` (in the sense that data shown into the url in `get request`, but not in `post`)

So just use `post` instead of `get` in `<form method>`

and `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

like:-

```
form action="service.php" method="POST">
    input type="text" name="txt1"> <br />
    input type="text" name="txt2"> <br />
    input type="submit" value="add"><br />
```

AND

```
<?PHP

echo "This is my first program in php";
$a= $_POST['txt1'];
$b= $_POST['txt2'];
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Comment: Define "more secure". In what respect? What if security is irrelevant? The `GET` form submission method has its uses.

Comment: @deceze added that explanation

Comment: It's still unclear why data not shown in the URL is "more secure", or in what scenarios it's "more secure". You can't make blanket statements like that, there's a lot more nuance to things relating to "security".

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$_GET` and `$_get` are two different variables. You must use capital letters. So PHP thinks you're referring to another variable.

This will work :

```
<?php
echo "This is my first program in php";
$a= $_GET['txt1'];
$b= $_GET['txt2'];
echo $a + $b;
```

If you're new to PHP, these two pages should help :
[Variable basics (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) and [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 1):

**GET Variable** name should be all in **CAPS**,

So your code might look something like this,

```
<?PHP

echo "This is my first program in php";
$a= $_GET['txt1'];
$b= $_GET['txt2'];
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

> **$_GET** is predefined reserved variable.

---

Also it's advisable to use **POST** method (as @Anant mentioned) to send sensitive data to server, You can access those data which is sent using **POST** method by **$_POST** variable.